# Cluster google map pins when using an object of markers instead of an array

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I'm managing this website: http://www.gprprojecten.nl
Basically what I'm doing with is is getting a stream of data from a webservice and chaching this. Afterwards I do all kinds of things to this data, including displaying all the projects on a google map.
Problem is, that as the projectnumber grows, the (custom)pins start to overlap (not visible, not clickable).

So I want to cluster my pins.

I started working on [a google maps clusterer library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/simple_example.html) using [A32.blog](http://a32.me/2012/05/handling-huge-amount-of-markers-on-google-maps-with-clusters/) as my starting point.

But now a problem arises. As I have chosen a client side filter system called [filter.js](https://github.com/jiren/filter.js), I depend on that way of using google maps, which is with objects rather then an array of markers as used in the clusterer library.

Here is the code I use to generate my map in combination with filter.js:

```
var googleMap = {
center_lat_lng: [52.14, 5.3],
map: null,
markers: {},
addMarker: function (project) {
    var that = this;
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('@Url.Content("~/Content/img/marker.png")',
        new google.maps.Size(63, 27),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(23, 27));
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(project.loclat, project.loclong),
        map: this.map,
        title: project.gebouwnaam,
        icon: image
    });

    marker.info_window_content = "<div class=\"gmapcontentwindow\"><h4>" + project.gebouwnaam + "</h4><img src=\"" + project.thumburl + "\" alt=\"" + project.gebouwnaam + "\" /><div class=\"gebouwdata\"><span class=\"date\">" + project.publicatiedatum + "</span><h5>" + project.plaats + "</h5><span>" + project.gebruiksfunctie + " | " + project.gebouwcategorie + "</span><span>" + project.licentiehouder + "</span><span class=\"stars " + project.rating + "\"></span>"
    if (project.akkoorddoorexpert == "True") {
        marker.info_window_content += "<span class=\"expert\"></span>"
    }
    var forwardUrl = '@Url.Content("~/Home/Details/")';
    marker.info_window_content += "<span  class=\"forward\"><a href=\"" + forwardUrl + project.id + "\" title=\"Bekijk " + project.gebouwnaam + " in detail\">Lees meer >></b></a></span></div></div>"
    this.markers[project.id] = marker

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        that.infowindow.setContent(marker.info_window_content)
        that.infowindow.open(that.map, marker);
    });
},

updateMarkers: function (filtering_result) {
    var google_map = this;
    $.each(google_map.markers, function () { this.setMap(null); })
    $.each(filtering_result, function () {
        google_map.markers[this.id].setMap(google_map.map);
    });
},

init: function () {
    var options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.center_lat_lng[0], this.center_lat_lng[1]),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), options)

    this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

    });
    //var markersarray = $(this.markers).toArray();
    //console.log(markersarray);
    //doet het nog niet???
    //http://a32.me/2012/05/handling-huge-amount-of-markers-on-google-maps-with-clusters/
    //var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(this.map, markersarray, {
    //  gridSize: 10,
    //  minimumClusterSize: 2
    //});
}
};
```

project is an object that is passed to the init function from filter.js

Comment: I don't understand your issue.  If you can access the markers (as google.maps.Marker objects) you can add them to the cluseterer (individually, if not via an array).

Comment: well, I don't understand either, but I can't seem to be able to get them into the clusterer, for starters, where would I place the call to the clusterer, in the init function?

Comment: You mean the [MarkerClusterer.addMarker](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html) call?  Or the creation of the MarkerClusterer object?

Comment: the latter, it seems to work if I just call it from document.ready but then I cannot access it (and modify it) on filter callback

Comment: Then you need to declare it in the global scope (or keep a reference to it in your object).

Comment: How stupid of me. Thank you for pointing this out. Add is as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the Marker Clusterer to the global scope or keep a reference to it in your object.